# How to make Windows Media Player library behave like Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, music-management

I have an issue with Media Player library... I don't need songs grouped by artists, albums, the need importing files, etc. I just need to browse my music by folders. Is this possible?

I basically need something like Windows Explorer + Media Player (with playback, shuffle, repeat and other Media Player features). If not possible in media player, is there any other player which has this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to browse by folder in media player but first you will need to define your music folder. Go to organize->manage libraries->music->add and add your music folder.Then simply go to Library->Music->Folder and your music will be displayed by folder.

If you wanna try some alternatives, [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) and [mediamonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it before. Still a little unsatisfactory though. If I insert a new usb drive for example, I'd have to add it to the library every time, and wait until its scanned. And media library doesn't provide any Explorer features (folder tree, files manipulation, etc.), it feels very limited... If anybody knows a player more like Windows Explorer (or exactly an Explorer extension), please share it here!

Comment: @Ognjen have you tried right clicking on your usb drive and selecting autoplay->Media player? I agree with you that WMP is of limitted functionality in this field.However you can browse to your desired mp3 folder and then select all songs using ctrl+a and selecting play in media player.Hope it helps anyway.